# How do i put a .env file in GitHub?

Tags: python, github, version-control

In most instances .env files for Python are in the .gitignore directory. However it's crucial for me to have my .env file in my private repository. I need to be able to git pull it to my local machines or my code does not run. Doing something simple such as:

```
import streamlit as st
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

st.title(os.getenv("MY_SECRET_KEY"))
```

Where MY_SECRET_KEY is defined in a **.env** file in the same directory. When i try to upload this to github desktop, github says the file is hidden, and when i `git pull` i can't even retreive it. It's gone!

How do i add my **.env** file to github, and have it available for use?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, remove the entry for .env from your `.gitignore` file, which is in the root of your file structure.